# MySQL data does not appear in tooltip

Tags: php

I want to show MySQL data inside a tooltip.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $abfrage = "SELECT * FROM tester";
    $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)){
        $Name=$row->Name;
        $Bech=$row->Beschreibung;
    }
?>

<a href="" title="<?=$Name?> <?=$Bech?>">Test Link</a>
```

It shows me an empty tooltip with nothing inside. If I print those two variables, the MySQL data appear. Is there any mistake in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: How many rows do you have? I'm guessing your last row is blank. Run a var_dump in your while statement and die after the while.

Comment: Do you have multiple rows you are fetching?  If you do a `var_dump($Name)` after your `while` loop, what do you see?  Also, avoid short open tags for best compatibility with other server configurations.

Comment: Try putting your `<a href="" ...></a>` inside your `while()` loop, as this will only echo out the last values of `$Name` and `$Bech`

Comment: Food for thought: Avoid `mysql*`, use `mysqli` ;-) deprecation now in effect.

Comment: What is wrong with fetching an array, instead of objects?

Comment: If i do a <code>var_dump($Name)</code> i see: string(20) "This is a headline 2". So the MySQL data appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This is in conjunction with Seth McClaine's answer.

Echo your values using:

```
<?php echo $Name; ?> <?php echo $Bech; ?>
```

Instead of `<?=$Name?> <?=$Bech?>`

The use of short tags is not recommended for something like this.

#### Reformatted code:

```
<?php
    $abfrage = "SELECT * FROM tester";
    $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis);
    $Name=$row->Name;
    $Bech=$row->Beschreibung;
?>

<a href="" title="<?php echo $Name; ?> <?php echo $Bech; ?>">Test Link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the first result remove the while...

```
 <?php
    $abfrage = "SELECT * FROM tester";
    $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis);
        $Name=$row->Name;
        $Bech=$row->Beschreibung;
?>

<a href="" title="<?=$Name?> <?=$Bech?>">Test Link</a>
```

Comment: Same result. Nothing changed.

Comment: @user2671171 Have you tried to echo your values? `<?php echo $Name; ?> <?php echo $Bech; ?>`

Comment: Fantastics it works now. Thank you. I dont know if i should open a new  question. If i want to style the single rows with css, where do i have to add the <span class="test">?

Comment: Yeah, i needed to echo the values.

Comment: @user2671171 That's good news. See my answer and accept Seth's and upvote mine. Seth deserves credit.

Comment: I have not enough reputation to upvote. So i just can accept one answer :(.

Comment: @user2671171 Good stuff! You can upvote as many answers as you want, even if there are more than one answer. Even mine (wink)

Comment: @user2671171 Thanks, much appreciated :) am glad the problem was resolved (*Peace*)